# git pull stats not shown any more

Tags: git

I use git to update my copy of a project when new features are added. Git provides a very nice summary of the changes that have been made, something like this:

```
intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.rst                             |  266 +++--
intro/numpy/advanced_operations.rst                         |   62 +-
intro/numpy/array_object.rst                                |  630 ++++++----
```

With this I can also follow the development of the project and it is quite useful.
At some point I made some personal changes to the source code of the project, but then I reverted it.
Since then, I think, the nice summary disappeared, and instead this line is shown each time I do `git pull`:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

How to revert things and make the summary appear again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little summary with the statistics is a consequence of the `git merge` operation, in fact by default it is called with the `--stat` option (to avoid the stats one can pass the `-n` or `--no-stat` option).
Since `git pull` is a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` the stats are shown by default.
If you are not seeing them any more probably your are doing a *rebase* instead of a *merge*.

So you can

- modify the `.git/config` file of your repo and comment the line `rebase = true` relative to the branch you are interested to. Be aware that this obviously changes the behaviour of the merging process from a `rebase` to a `merge` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/804115/1611927) for details)
- use the command `git pull --stat` to force the stats to appear when pulling